# Determinant of a Column Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

What is the determinant of a column matrix? I figured it would not exist, or equal 0, knowing only the method for solving square matrices, but is there a different method for finding such a determinant?

Comment: It is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Determinant is defined only for square matrices.
Determinant of a non-square matrix is not zero.
It is just not defined.

Your problem can be thought of like finding square root of -9 or maybe arcsin(1.5) both of which are not defined (or do not exist).

So, the determinant of a column matrix is defined only when it is a 1x1 matrix, which equals the lone element.

Comment: But we use $\sqrt{-9}=3i$ all the time...

Comment: @DanUznanski No. $(3i)^2=-9$. There's a difference.

Comment: Well, okay, $\sqrt{-9}=\pm3i$

Comment: i is a representation of sqrt(-1). it is not a "real" number.

Comment: @DanUznanski That's worse.$f\hspace{2 mm} \mathbb{R}^+\cup \{ 0\} \to \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{ 0\} : f(x) = \sqrt{ x}$.

Comment: @frederick99, I think ' _square root of -9_ ' is **not** a proper example here. Example of arcsin(1.5) is enough. In my opinion removing the example of 
 ' _square root of -9_ ' would make your answer better.

Comment: @Md.AbuNafeeIbnaZahid I disagree. :) They're both equally apt.

Comment: they do exist depending on your base set... if you are working with complex numbers, they both exist... they do not exist in the real space...